# Use last click to show only one popup

Tags: jquery, html

When the user has clicked on the desired clickTarget, then add a class to show the warning.

But when the user clicks on another field/clickTarget, it should hide the currently shown popup and then display the next popup.

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var clickTarget = event.target.classList[1],
    clickParent = event.target.classList[0];
    
  if (clickTarget === 'kyc-flag') {
    $(event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling).addClass('kyc-warning');
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.kycFlagIcon').removeClass('kyc-warning');
  }, 1500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row middle-xs center-xs ">
  <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-set">
      <span class="label">Company Name</span>
      <input name="MerchantName" class="bp-company-name-field kyc-flag" placeholder="Company name" type="text" value="Brand P" title="Company Name" disabled="" required="">
      <span class="kycFlagIcon bp-company-name-field">!</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-set">
      <span class="label">Username</span>
      <input name="UserName" placeholder="Username" class="bp-username-field valid" type="text" value="Branded" required="" data-rule-minlength="2" data-rule-maxlength="255" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Working js fiddle progress example - https://jsfiddle.net/vrwfa2s5/

Comment: Do you have example in jsFiddle?

Comment: Added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/vrwfa2s5/3/

You'll have to restructure your javascript code a little.

You can target the element instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  $('.kyc-flag').on('click', function() {

    $('.kycFlagIcon').removeClass('kyc-warning');

    $(this).closest('.input-set').find('.kycFlagIcon').toggleClass('kyc-warning');

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `nextSibling.nextSibling` isn't selecting the element you expect.

Assuming you're attempting to add the class to the sibling `span` of the clicked `.kyc-flag` then you can use jQuery's `is()` method to determine the clicked element, then `next()` to get the sibling to add the class to. Try this:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);

  if ($target.is('.kyc-flag')) {
    var $flag = $target.next();
    $flag.addClass('kyc-warning');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $flag.removeClass('kyc-warning');
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```

```css
.kycFlagIcon {
  opacity: 0;
}

.kyc-warning {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row middle-xs center-xs ">
  <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-set">
      <span class="label">Company Name</span>
      <input name="MerchantName" class="bp-company-name-field kyc-flag" placeholder="Company name" type="text" value="Brand P" title="Company Name" disabled="" required="">
      <span class="kycFlagIcon bp-company-name-field">!</span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-set">
      <span class="label">Username</span>
      <input name="UserName" placeholder="Username" class="bp-username-field valid" type="text" value="Branded" required="" data-rule-minlength="2" data-rule-maxlength="255" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if thats the issue. Otherwise the popup wouldnt show up. Which it does. The issue is hiding the previous popup when another popup is selected.